# Display Custom listview from "List"

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am using this type of data structure

```
static List<String> displaypart = new ArrayList<String>();
static List<String> displayitalic = new ArrayList<String>();
static List<String> displayA_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static List<String> displayAS_name = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I have added their values as string from database by this code

```
String strquery="select * from Articles where AS_name LIKE '%"+querytext+"%'";
    cur=db.rawQuery(strquery,null); 
    if(cur!=null&&cur.moveToFirst())
    {
    do
                {
                    Flag.displaypart.add(cur.getString(7));
                    Flag.displayA_name.add(cur.getString(2));
                    Flag.displayitalic.add(cur.getString(8));
                    Flag.displayAS_name.add(cur.getString(3));
                    Flag.displayDesc_art.add(cur.getString(4));
                    i++;
                }
                while(cur.moveToNext());
    }  
}
```

My requirement is to show these data in listview. Each cell consists of 4 textviews. For that I made

**query_cell.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/querylinearlayout">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"

    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView                                 // this textview just gives the black color margin
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to inflate this in Listview !
**query_fragment.xml** consist of a listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF" 
android:id="@+id/queryrelativelayout">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My question is how can I inflate `query_cell.xml` into this listview ?

For that I made a reference of listview in `onCreateView` like this

```
listview1 = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

I have seen some tutorials making the custom adapter extending BaseAdapter, some extending ArrayList, I am also confused what should be its constructor consists like, & also about `getView` that holder should be used or not.

What should my CustomAdapter look like. How would you do this? I also appreciate different coding style if you have your own way of implementation.

Please help

Thanks in Advance

AFTET SQUONK ANSWER Logcat

```
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:302)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:174)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:151)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.support.v4.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:93)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:89)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at com.vivekwarde.indianconstitution.DBAdapter.queryArticles(DBAdapter.java:271)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at com.vivekwarde.indianconstitution.QueryFragment.onCreateView(QueryFragment.java:44)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
07-28 23:13:14.979: E/AndroidRuntime(3040):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You say you are getting the strings from your database - in that case it would be better to use a `CursorAdapter` such as the `SimpleCursorAdapter` class.

Comment: I have already got string from database & get stored in `displaypart `,`displayitalic `, `displayA_name`, `displayAS_name`

Comment: Yes, I know but that is a really bad way of doing it. Using a `Cursor` with `SimpleCursorAdapter` will allow each column of the `Cursor` to be automatically bound to each `TextView`. Much simpler than trying to deal with four `ArrayLists`.

Comment: How can use a Cursor with SimpleCursorAdapter which according to you will allow each column of the Cursor to be automatically bound to each TextView,also why is it bad way

Comment: see my edit of how do I get data from database & storing it in `List`

Comment: See my answer with an example of using `SimpleCursorAdapter` to bind four db columns to four `TextViews`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic example of using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` ...

```
public void initAdapter(Context ctx, ListView myListView) {
    String strquery = "SELECT unique_column_name AS _id,column1,column2,column3,column4 FROM MY_TABLE";
    cur = db.rawQuery(strquery,null);

    if (cur != null && cur.getCount() > 0) {
        String[] fromColumns = { "column1", "column2", "column3", "column4" };
        int[] toViews = { R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4 };

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(ctx, 
                R.layout.query_cell, cur, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

When calling the method from an `Activity` use...

```
initAdapter(this, listView1);
```

From a `Fragment` use...

```
initAdapter(getActivity(), listView1);
```

In the above, the `fromColumns` array is the names of the database columns you want to map to the `TextViews` and the `toViews` array are the resource identifiers of each `TextView` in your list item layout (your query_cell,xml layout file).

In the `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor you then just pass in the list item layout resource id (R.layout.query_cell) and the columns and views arrays and `SimpleCursorAdapter` will do all of the rest of the work for you.

Comment: 1 error in 2nd last line `The constructor SimpleCursorAdapter(DBAdapter, int, Cursor, String[], int[], int) is undefined`

Comment: OK, change the first parameter `this` to the `Context` of your `Activity`.

Comment: App crashes see logcat in question, I think it needs some sort of '_id' ? But nothing in my database exists '_id' nor in my code, any reason ?

Comment: Ah, yes. A `CursorAdapter` needs a unique id column named `_id`. Do you have any columns such as an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT?

Comment: no I dont have any INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT column in my database. BTW i get rid of this problem by this [answer](INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT), & changed my query to `String strquery="select  rowid _id,* from Articles where AS_name LIKE '%"+querytext+"%'";` ! Now I am getting null pointer exception , because 1 st parameter of SimpleCursorAdapter is mContext which is null

Comment: I have used `Context mContext;` declared globally in DBAdapter, Also tried to call `static Context mContext;` which is declared globally in QueryFragment by using `QueryFragment.mContext`

Comment: When you call the method with that code in from your `Activity` simply pass `this` in as a parameter. If you are calling the method from a `Fragment` pass `getActivity()` as a paramater. Example, `someMethod(this)` or `someMethod(getActivity())`. Don't hold onto the `Context` if you can avoid it - simply pass it as the first parameter of the `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor.

Comment: @VivekWarde : See the edit to my code example. I'm passing a `Context` as a parameter called `ctx` then using that as the first parameter of the `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor.

Comment: Thank you I did the same, Null pointer ex is gone for mContext but I am getting NullPointer Exception in the last line of code which is  `QueryFragment.listview1.setAdapter(adapter);` listview1 is null

Comment: OK. Make sure you have initialised the `ListView` in your `Fragment` using your `listview1 = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);` call then pass a reference to `listView1`. See my edited method.

Comment: Oh thanks its my fault, everything is ok & I want to make its onClicklistener & show the selected item text in dialogbox, Please tell how can I make its onclicklistener

Comment: I successfully made its onclick but please tell me how can I get the selected textview text into string so that I can display it in dialog

Comment: @VivekWarde : That's something you should ask in a separate question as it doesn't really relate to your original question here.